# Find full string using partial string lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

I tried to find the whole string in a table without writing the full string.

Example:

```
maintable = {"SecondString", "FirstString"}
c = "First"
```

How would I be able to use string `c` to find the whole name of FirstString without typing the whole string name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to search the table:

```
for k,v in pairs(maintable) do
    if v:match(c) then print(k,v) end
end
```